# Trying to output an answer with linq

Tags: c#, linq, excel, csv

I've been working on a program that joins two arrays by an identifier called "SeqID" and outputting an answer to a CSV file.

Whenever I output this answer to a file it prints out the same answer for a bunch of lines then finally moves onto the next answer and prints that out for a bunch of lines and so forth. I think there may be a problem in the loop but I do not see it. Here is the code...

```
    private void executeBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //NET OIL VARIANCE MATHEMATICS
        if (netOilRadBtn.Checked)
        {
            using (var sw = new StreamWriter("testNetOil.csv"))
            {
                var items = netOil.Zip(seqNum, (oil, seq) => new { Oil = oil, Seq = seq });
                var items2 = netOil2.Zip(seqNum2, (oil, seq) => new { Oil = oil, Seq = seq });
                sw.WriteLine("Lease Name, Field Name, Reservoir, Operator, County, ST, Majo, Resv Cat, Discount Rate, Net Oil Interest, Net Gas Interest, Working Interest, Gross Wells, Ultimate Oil, Ultimate Gas, Gross Oil, Gross NGL, Gross Gas, Net Oil, Net Gas, Net NGL, Revenue To Int., Oper. Expense, Total Invest., Revenue Oil, Revenue Gas, Operating Profit, Revenue NGL, Disc Net Income, SEQ, Well ID, INC ASN, Life Years, Own Qual, Production Tax, NET OIL VARIANCE");

                foreach (var item in items.Join(items2, i => i.Seq, i => i.Seq, (a, b) => new
                {SeqID = a.Seq, Answer = this.GetTheAnswer(Convert.ToDouble(a.Oil), Convert.ToDouble(b.Oil)) 

                }))

                {
                    foreach (var s in item.SeqID)
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine(item.Answer);
                    }
```

Basically all I want for this code to achieve is to only print out **one answer for the matching seqNum's** in the two different arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In

```
foreach (var s in item.SeqID)
```

you loop through each `char` in `SeqID`. I can't imagine that's useful. Just remove the loop and only do `sw.WriteLine(item.Answer)`.

Comment: Thanks, the matching seqNum's also have more data with them such as Name and Date created, is there anyway I'd be able to print those out with them?

Comment: You better put that in a new question with some sample data. Hard to tell without.